# Can MathJax extract the css separately?

Tags: javascript, css

I want to separate out the `css` in `MathJax` and generate a `css` file for the `latex` to use in unison to render the `latex` in advance, so that only the `html` of the `latex` rendered in advance is saved. When I load the `latex`, I only need to load the html of the current `latex` and an overall `css` file, rather than drawing the `latex` as the page loads.

This way the individual ends don't have to care about how the latex is rendered, they just need to reference a unified `css` file first and then reference the `html` of the rendered `latex`

Is this approach possible, please? If not is there another way?

My English is not very good, these words are translated using translation software, if there are any problems I hope you can ask, please bear with me.

Thank you for your answer.

I'm trying to get the current style in the `head` every time I render a formula, but there's no end to this, so I'd like to be able to extract a unified `css` file.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research.  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.